# Graph navigation with C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory, traversal, directed-graph

I having a bit of a quandry trying to come up with a good algorithm to navigate the following graph.

[alt text http://www.archimedesinc.biz/images/StackOverflow/Tree.jpg](http://www.archimedesinc.biz/images/StackOverflow/Tree.jpg)

If a user chooses "Table 21" as a starting point, I need to be able to get the path to any other table from that starting table.

EX: If the user chooses "Table 21" as a start and then adds a value from "Table 8", I need to create the following path "**Table 21** -> **Table 12** -> **Table 9** -> **Table 6** -> **Table 8**", all of the weights between the tables are the same.

I seem to have forgotten my skills in dealing with directed graphs, and can't think of a good algorithm. I'm not asking for a solution, but just a push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breadth-first search will find a shortest path: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 3):

Since you said the edges are all of the same weight, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) (my usual first choice for this sort of thing) will just degrade to [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) so I suggest using that for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose from a number of algorithms for determining the shortest path. [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=User%20Manual) is good at this sort of thing.